# how to scroll on a page which has long content?

Tags: css, scroll

I am building a website which has 2 sidebar and one column between sidebars. Sidebars and middle column all have long content which force the user to scroll down. but here is the problem. Sometime posts which goes to middle column, are not as long as sidebars. I mean less than sidebars. so if users scroll down, they reach to end of the post and from then on, middle column will be empty but sidebars still have content. I need to scroll so that middle column reach to the end at same time with sidebars regardless of which one is longer or shorter!

If you scroll down on this page you'll find out that sometimes sidebars move and sometimes middle column: [a link](http://digiato.com/article/2017/09/18/%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D9%86%D9%88%DA%A9%DB%8C%D8%A7-9-%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A8%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%AF%D9%88%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this could be done via css3 property `position: sticky`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> It's treated as relatively positioned until its containing block
>   crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed.

The idea is to fix (to stick) your middle column until sidebars are scrolled down.

Also, [HERE](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sticky-positioning-with-nothing-but-css--cms-24042) is the great post relating to your question which includes detailed explanation, caveats and sticky-polyfill. They have 2 columns: the first one (named "Scroll Down!") which can be considered as your left sidebar and the second one (named "Sidebar") which can be considered as your middle column.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but don't you think sticky position is unsafe? because some browsers specially old browser don't support that. Am i right?

Comment: Yeah, IE has no this feature according to actual Browsers compatibility table. If you want to support old browsers, use javascript polyfill. There are some popular position-sticky polyfills, e.g. https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill, you can try it in your project. And if you will have any issues with it, I suggest you to post a new question.